# C# HttpClient throws Exception on no Sucess Status Codes

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin, httpclient

i got a very weird problem. When I request a Webpage that return an Status Code that isn't a 2** Statuscode than HttpClient throws an ecxeption.

Implementation:

```
try {

    //post-anfrage an webservice starten
    var request = await httpClient.PostAsync(SettingsPage.WebServiceURL + site,
                content);

    if (!request.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        if (request.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
            await User.Instance.Logout();
        }
        var message = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        RaiseErrorMessage(null, message);
    }

    SaveCookies(request);

    timer.Change(PING_INTERVAL, PING_INTERVAL);

    return request;
}
catch (TaskCanceledException e) {
    RaiseConnectionError(null, "Verbindung zu Webservice fehlgeschlagen!");
    return null;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    RaiseConnectionError(null, "Es ist etwas schief gelaufen..." + System.Environment.NewLine + "Bitte Support Kontaktieren!");
    Debug.WriteLine("AppWarehouse.pro: " + ex.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine("AppWarehouse.pro: " + ex.StackTrace);
    return null;
}
}
```

I don't understand why it does what it does. For me there is no reason for that behaviour. I'd be happy about a fix or help to fix it.

Comment: !request.IsSuccessStatusCode  - this throws an error if the StatusCode is not in the 2** range. If you're getting 404 for example that line of code will cause an error. You are posting content and you want to know if the operation went as expected.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake not that isn't what causes the problem. It still throws the exception called HttpRequestException.

Comment: So, the code is throwing an exception before the if statement? If that is the case then could you confirm what type the httpClient is please?

Comment: @DanielHollinrake Yes before the if-statement... HttpClient is from System.Net.Http;

Comment: How do you know that there is a response status i.e 404 or 403 instead of an HResult?

Comment: @Barnstokkr Because i return in my WebAPI an explicit Statuscode

Comment: What is the HttpStatus code that is generated when the HttpClient throws an exception? Can you please add the `Debug.WriteLine("AppWarehouse.pro: " + ex.Message);` message. 
Stating that your API returns a StatusCode isn't very helpful in helping you. I'm assuming that this code isn't your actual code since, there is no way you can get the StatusCode by returning a `null`. And, HttpRequestException is only thrown when an HResult exception occurs.

Comment: @Barnstokkr ex.Message is just saying that an error occurd while sending that request... I return null, because the Function wants the request result back. Therefore i return null, because i haven't got an result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it... It was a strange behaviour from Xamarin combined with an assembly.